# C# type definition using keyword with variable type

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to create generic type definition using `using` in C#?

For example, I would want to do the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  using TPred<T> = Expression<Func<T, bool>>;

  public class Predicates
  {
    public static TPred<T> False<T> => f => false;

    public static TPred<T> True<T> => f => true;

    public static TPred<T> Or<T> (this TPred<T> expr1, TPred<T> expr2)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I believe that it is not possible, but wanted to verify it with wise folks from Stack Overflow ;).

Comment: A `using` directive never creates a new type, generic or not. If you're actually asking if you can use *aliases* with generic types, that's a different matter... but I don't *think* there's such a thing as a generic alias.

Comment: Posting answer to avoid people jumping between sites as the other question is more involved.

It is not possible. Further, parametrizing alias is not allowed as well, e.g. `Expr = Expression;` wouldn't allow to specify the following type `Expr<Func<T, bool>>`.

In short, don't mix aliasing with generics.